# android kernel libm pow(float,float) implementation

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ieee-754, pow

I am testing corner cases on the `pow` call(`#include <math.h>`), specifically `pow(-1, Inf)`.

On my desktop (Ubuntu) I get the result 1.0, this is in accordance with the 2008 IEEE floating point specification.

I run the same test when running the Android Gingerbread kernel and I get NaN returned.

I have looked around and can see that there is indeed many implementations of `pow` in the standard libraries for different platforms and in the case `pow(-1, Inf)` they are coded to produce different results.

The question is which one should be deemed correct?  Any Ideas or thoughts?

I apologize if I am posting on the wrong forum, I followed the link from the android developer resources and ended up here.

Answer (score 7):

The C standard is perfectly clear on this point (§F.9.4.4); there's no room for "ideas or thoughts":

> pow(−1, ±∞) returns 1.

Annex F applies only if an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, but there is no question that 1.0 is the right answer.

I suspect that this is a Java-ism that has leaked over into the NDK.  (Java defines `pow(-1,infinity)` to be `NaN`):

> If the absolute value of the first argument equals 1 and the second argument is infinite, then the result is NaN.

**Edit:**
Since Matteo objects that this "makes no sense", I'll offer a few sentences of explanation for why the committee made this choice.  Although lim_{n->inf} (-1)^n does not exist in the real numbers, we must remember that *floating-point numbers are not real numbers*, and in fact, for all sufficiently large floating-point numbers `y`, `pow(-1,y)` is `+1`.  This is because all sufficiently large floating-point numbers are even integers.  From this perspective, it is quite reasonable to define `pow(-1,infinity)` to be `+1`, and this turns out to actually lead to more useful behavior in some floating-point computations.

There are a surprising number of extremely competent mathematicians (as well as very skilled programmers and compiler writers) involved with both the C and the IEEE-754 committees, and they do not make these decisions flippantly.  Every standard has bugs, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Mathematically speaking it makes no sense, since the limit for n->+inf of a^n does not exist for a<0; if it were in my power it would be NaN.

Comment: @Matteo: Floating point numbers are not real numbers.  Both the C committee and the IEEE-754 committee thought carefully about this before choosing to standardize the behavior that we did.